# How can you change a single bit of a bitmap inside a char array in C?

Tags: c, arrays, bitmap, char

I'm forced to use a char array as a bitmap. For instance, this would be a 32-bit bitmap:

```
char bitmap[4];
```

Beforehand, I have initialized every single byte of this array to 0. My question is, how can I change a single bit of this array to be the one I want? I'm looking for a function with a similar structure to this, where the bitmap is passed as a parameter, along with the index of the bit we want to change and the value we want to change it to:

```
set_bit(char *bitmap, int bit, int value);
```

They force me to use a char array instead of an unsigned char array. It would also be useful to have a get_bit function with a similar structure that only asks for the bitmap and the bit to be probed as arguments.

Thank you in advance.

EDIT: I fixed the type of the bitmap in the set_bit definition

Comment: How will you connect `char bitmap[4];` with `set_bit(int bitmap, int bit, int value);`?

Comment: It will be like `bitmap[bit/CHAR_BIT] = (bitmap[bit/CHAR_BIT] & ~(1 << (bit % CHAR_BIT))) | ((value != 0) << (bit % CHAR_BIT));` where `bitmap` is the array. `CHAR_BIT` is from `limits.h`.

Comment: @MikeCAT the idea is to pass the bitmap as a parameter to the set_bit function, specifying the bit that is going to be changed as "bit" and the value we want to change it to in "value"

Comment: @MikeCAT Sorry for the misunderstanding. The definition of set_bit has been corrected

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
void setbit(void *arr, size_t bit, unsigned val)
{
    unsigned char *ucarr = arr;     // void * to prevent compiler warnings when you pass other type pointer. 
    size_t index = bit >> 3;        //>>3 is == divide by 8 which is number of bits in char on most systems. Index number
    unsigned char mask = 1 << (bit & 7);  // &7 - bit number in the 8 bits charackter

    ucarr[index] &= ~mask;               // zero the bit
    ucarr[index] |= mask * (!!val);      // set the bit to the value (1 of var nonzero, 0 if var == 0) 

}
```

or if you are sure that `val` will be `1` or `0` a bit more efficient version (few clocks)

```
void setbit1(void *arr, size_t bit, unsigned val)
{
    unsigned char *ucarr = arr;
    size_t index = bit >> 3;
    size_t bitindex = bit & 7;
    unsigned char mask = 1 << bitindex;

    ucarr[index] &= ~mask;
    ucarr[index] |= val << bitindex; 
}
```

- some other versions https://godbolt.org/z/JGK-Zo

or a bit more portable version (CHAR_BIT up to 256)

```
#define CHO     (((CHAR_BIT >> 1) & 1)*2 + ((CHAR_BIT >> 2) & 1)*4 + ((CHAR_BIT >> 3) & 1)*8 + ((CHAR_BIT >> 4) & 1)*16 + ((CHAR_BIT >> 5) & 1)*32 + ((CHAR_BIT >> 6) & 1)*64 + ((CHAR_BIT >> 7) & 1)*128 + ((CHAR_BIT >> 8) & 1)*256)

void setbit(void *arr, size_t bit, unsigned val)
{
    unsigned char *ucarr = arr;
    size_t index = bit >> CHO;
    unsigned char mask = 1 << (bit & (CHAR_BIT - 1));

    ucarr[index] &= ~mask;
    ucarr[index] |= mask * (!!val); 
}

void setbit1(void *arr, size_t bit, unsigned val)
{
    unsigned char *ucarr = arr;
    size_t index = bit >> CHO;
    size_t bitindex = bit & (CHAR_BIT - 1);
    unsigned char mask = 1 << bitindex;

    ucarr[index] &= ~mask;
    ucarr[index] |= val << bitindex; 
}
```

Comment: Code without explanation is not an answer. Stack Overflow is not a free coding service, and people should not be led to believe it is. Answers should explain concepts, conveying knowledge to readers. The reason `void *` is used and is assigned to `unsigned char *` should be stated. The reason why this has defined behavior should be stated. The origin of the constants 3 and 7 should be stated. How the bitwise operators create the desired result should be stated.